# How do I specify the visibility of an relationship in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am creating class diagrams for C# code and I'd like to specify the visibility of relationships. I'm using named arrows to specify the relationships but I dont think its right to put the visibility signal (+, -, ~, #) together with the name. I also don't want to repeat the relationship as a property in the class.

Please tell me if I wasn't clear enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question. For me, it's not a problem to put the visibility of a property with the property name like this :

```
  + PropertyClassA                    + PropertyClassB
<------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: yep, that's the question, thank you. I thought doing this is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what IDE you use to create your diagram, but let me suggest you this one http://www.softwareideas.net/ which, I hope, will help you and avoid syntaxic question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a Mac.